# Save Identity profile in separate database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, profile

I am planning to implement MVC 5.0 ASP.Net identity in a brand new application. I referred to the Microsoft article http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to add the customer profile information in a separate table other than the identity tables.

However according my requirement, I would like to store the customer profile information in a separate database in order to segregate the user identity information and customer profile information in database level. The Identity uses single data store while creating user and the profile information, whereas I need to set two different store for the user and profile information. Do Anyone have any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply write a custom `UserStore` class and extend default `UserStore` class. Consider this simple example:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    // other codes

    // Add your extra profile information 
    // By Adding NotMapped attribute EF omits this and dose not puts in Identity's table
    [NotMapped]
    public Profile Profile { get; set; }
}

public class Profile
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ExtraData { get; set; }
    // other properties 
}
```

Now we need custom User Store to put and fetch data from 2 DB

```
public class MyUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser>
{     
    public MyUserStore(DbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
         // other implementation for second DB
    }

    public override Task CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
          // save Profile object to separate DB 
          _mySecondDB.Save(User.Id, user.Profile);
          return base.CreateAsync(user);
    }

    public override Task UpdateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        // same pattern as CreateAsync
    }

    public override Task DeleteAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        // same pattern as CreateAsync
    }


    public override async Task<ApplicationUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
    {
        var user = await base.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        user.Profile = _mySecondDB.FindProfileByUserId(userId);
        return user;
    }

    public override Task<ApplicationUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
    {
        // same pattern as FindByIdAsync
    }
}
```

Now you just need to inject your custom User Store in Identity pipeline. To do so change `ApplicationUserManager.Create` static method in `App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs` like this:

```
public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
{
   var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(
       new MyUserStore(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
   // other codes 
}
```